# r package caret-Print iteration when using parallel

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there anyway we could print iteration when using the `caret::train` function in parallel? I know there is option called verbose but it seems it doesn't print anything if I use multicore.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? It directs output in a non-standard way. When I use multicore with it, I don't get any logs but I do with regular R.

Comment: Hi Max! I tried with both R studio and R server but non of them prints log if I use registerdomc/makecluster. After some research, I've found that caret package is not the problem but foreach package is the problem. There are some tricks to print out logs. However, most of tricks has to be done inside of foreach loop or the cores have to be registered via makecluster function. But, as you might know, registering cores by makecluster function is just way slower than doMC to run foreach loop(The creator of both packages confirm this). But still, I'm seeking for any other tricks to print of logs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a solution.
All we need is to register cores via makeCluster function.

```
library(doSNOW)
cl <- makeCluster(30, outfile="")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
```

In this way, the log will be printed in console.
I've tested on regular R/ Rstudio/ Rserver in mac/window/ubuntu (even AWS)

For example,

```
iris <- iris[1:100,]
iris$Species <- as.factor(as.character(iris$Species))

tc <- trainControl(method="LGOCV",
                   summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
                   classProb=T,verboseIter=TRUE)
train.rf <- train(Species ~ .,data=iris, 
                  method="rf", trControl=tc, 
                   metric =  "ROC")
```

will print

```
Type: EXEC 
loaded caret and set parent environment
Type: EXEC 
loaded caret and set parent environment
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample01: mtry=2 
+ Resample01: mtry=3 
- Resample01: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample02: mtry=2 
- Resample01: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample01: mtry=4 
- Resample02: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample02: mtry=3 
- Resample01: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample02: mtry=4 
- Resample02: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample03: mtry=2 
- Resample02: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample03: mtry=3 
- Resample03: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample03: mtry=4 
- Resample03: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample04: mtry=2 
- Resample03: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample04: mtry=3 
- Resample04: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample04: mtry=4 
- Resample04: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample05: mtry=2 
- Resample04: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample05: mtry=3 
- Resample05: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample05: mtry=4 
- Resample05: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample06: mtry=2 
- Resample05: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample06: mtry=3 
- Resample06: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample06: mtry=4 
- Resample06: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample07: mtry=2 
- Resample06: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
- Resample07: mtry=2 
+ Resample07: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample07: mtry=4 
- Resample07: mtry=3 
- Resample07: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample08: mtry=2 
+ Resample08: mtry=3 
- Resample08: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample09: mtry=2 
- Resample08: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample08: mtry=4 
- Resample09: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample09: mtry=3 
- Resample08: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample09: mtry=4 
- Resample09: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample10: mtry=2 
- Resample09: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample10: mtry=3 
- Resample10: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample10: mtry=4 
- Resample10: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample11: mtry=2 
- Resample10: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample11: mtry=3 
- Resample11: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample11: mtry=4 
- Resample11: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample12: mtry=2 
- Resample11: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample12: mtry=3 
- Resample12: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample12: mtry=4 
- Resample12: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample13: mtry=2 
- Resample12: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample13: mtry=3 
- Resample13: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample13: mtry=4 
- Resample13: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample14: mtry=2 
- Resample14: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample14: mtry=4 
- Resample14: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample15: mtry=2 
- Resample15: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample15: mtry=3 
- Resample15: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample15: mtry=4 
- Resample13: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample14: mtry=3 
- Resample15: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample16: mtry=2 
- Resample14: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample16: mtry=3 
- Resample16: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample16: mtry=4 
- Resample16: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample17: mtry=2 
- Resample17: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample17: mtry=4 
- Resample17: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample18: mtry=2 
- Resample18: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample18: mtry=3 
- Resample16: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample17: mtry=3 
- Resample18: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample18: mtry=4 
- Resample17: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample19: mtry=2 
- Resample18: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample19: mtry=3 
- Resample19: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample19: mtry=4 
- Resample19: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample20: mtry=2 
- Resample19: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample20: mtry=3 
- Resample20: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample20: mtry=4 
- Resample20: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample21: mtry=2 
- Resample20: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample21: mtry=3 
- Resample21: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample21: mtry=4 
- Resample21: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
- Resample21: mtry=4 
+ Resample22: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample22: mtry=3 
- Resample22: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample23: mtry=2 
- Resample22: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample22: mtry=4 
- Resample23: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample23: mtry=3 
- Resample22: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample23: mtry=4 
- Resample23: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample24: mtry=2 
- Resample23: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample24: mtry=3 
- Resample24: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample24: mtry=4 
- Resample24: mtry=3 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample25: mtry=2 
- Resample24: mtry=4 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample25: mtry=3 
- Resample25: mtry=2 
Type: EXEC 
+ Resample25: mtry=4 
- Resample25: mtry=3 
- Resample25: mtry=4 
Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting mtry = 2 on full training set
```

Comment: Same for RStudio, Win7 64-bit, R version 3.3.2, packages: `randomForest_4.6-12`, `doSNOW_1.0.14`, `snow_0.4-2`, `iterators_1.0.8`, `foreach_1.4.3`, `caret_6.0-73`.

Comment: Thanks this works, however accuracy is missing. How we print accuracy in the text file?