# R - caret - Print iteration when using parallel backend

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-caret, doparallel

I would like to generate progress printing while running a parallel back-end with the caret package.

Same question and solution here, yet the solution does not work for me, any help would be appreciated: 
[r package caret-Print iteration when using parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24610593/r-package-caret-print-iteration-when-using-parallel/45356211#45356211)

Version info is the same as linked above.

```
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

other attached packages:
[1] randomForest_4.6-12 doSNOW_1.0.14       snow_0.4-2          plyr_1.8.4          gbm_2.1.3           survival_2.41-3    
[7] caret_6.0-76        ggplot2_2.2.1       lattice_0.20-34     doParallel_1.0.10   iterators_1.0.8     foreach_1.4.3
```

Solution that does not work:

> library(doSNOW)
>
> library(caret)
>
> cl <- makeCluster(2, outfile="")
>
> registerDoSNOW(cl)
>
> iris <- iris[1:100,]
>
> iris$Species <- as.factor(as.character(iris$Species))
>
> tc <- trainControl(method="LGOCV",
>                       summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,
>                       classProb=T,verboseIter=TRUE)
>
> train.rf <- train(Species ~ .,data=iris, 
>                      method="rf", trControl=tc, 
>                      metric =  "ROC")

```
Loading required package: randomForest
randomForest 4.6-12
Type rfNews() to see new features/changes/bug fixes.

Attaching package: ‘randomForest’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

margin

Aggregating results
Selecting tuning parameters
Fitting mtry = 2 on full training set
```

I also made a modification to the outfile statement in makeCluster to a text file and it did generate a text file in my directory.

```
cl <- makeCluster(2, outfile="progress.txt")
```

Is there anyway to work with this to make it print in the R console?

Thank you

Comment: Are you running this in Rstudio or in a plain R session?

Comment: Running RStudio Version 1.0.143

Comment: Try `verbose = TRUE` in `train` part as well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I gave it a try and still doesn't print into the console.